# Access vba- add specific amounts of records to table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have 2 textboxes, TextboxA and TextboxB on user form. The user types a number in TextboxA and another larger number in TextboxB. the VBA command is to calculate the difference between the numbers and then insert said number of records into tblA. data in the field "ReceiptNr" is to start with TextboxA value, and then increase with one upto and including the amount of TextBoxB .This would be an onclick event. The event is also to ensure that the value from TextboxA is not in the table tblA. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function as a skeleton - just pass value to the two parameters:

```
Public Sub InsertEmptyRecords(ByVal lngRecords As Long, ByVal lngNumber As Long)

  Dim rstInsert   As DAO.Recordset
  Dim lngLoop     As Long

  Set rstInsert = Me.RecordsetClone

  With rstInsert
    For lngLoop = 1 To lngRecords
      .AddNew
        .Fields("ReceiptNr").Value = lngNumber + lngLoop
      .Update
    Next
    .Close
  End With

  Set rstInsert = Nothing

End Sub
```